# Intel XDK: set href in sprite button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intel-xdk

I'm developing an application in *Intel XDK* and want to set the `href` of a sprite button via javascript.

I've tried:

- `document.getElementById('button').href`
- `document.getElementById('button').src`

with jQuery via `setAttribute`..

Anyone who can tell me what I should do to set the href of a sprite button in *intel XDK*?

EDIT:

I'm using this code now:

```
var arr = [{
  "url": "http://www.example.com/"
}]

for(j =0; j < arr.length; j++){

  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
                        window.location.href = arr[this.id].url;                   
                     });
}
```

The arr[] is declared on top of the file. The arr[] has more data but for example I only show this.

When I try to access it in this code it gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined anonymous function`

I have tested this outside the `.addEventListener` code, and that works.

How can I access the `arr[]` from within this code?

Thanks

EDIT 2: I have found the solution for my problem. It had something to do with the variable scope. By calling `this.id` instead of `j` I can access the right elements in the `arr` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('button').href
```

In above code you are trying to get `button` element which is `sprite button` which doesn't have `src` or `href` element you can use click event to go to other page using below code.

```
var myLinkArray = [{"id":"1","url":"www.example.com"}]
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function () {
window.location.href = myLinkArray[0].url;
});
```

You cann't **directly pass argument** to click event but can use defined array inside click event function.

This code add event listener for `click` event and redirect to given `href`.

```
var arr = [{
  "url": "http://www.example.com/"
}]
for(j =0; j < arr.length; j++){
    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
                        window.location.href = arr[j].url;
    });
}
```

There is no need of `for` loop. You can directly access url using following code:

```
var arr = [{
  "url": "http://www.example.com/"
}]
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.location.href = arr[0].url;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution works indeed, however I want to pass an array from where I want to get the url and set it to the href. But it keeps giving me an error that says that it can't recognise the array.

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener("click", function (arr) {
window.location.href = arr[j].getlink;
});

Comment: Can you show me what value of array is? Where is it defined?

Comment: It's an array which get filled with json data. So the array looks like [{"id":"1","url":"www.example.com"}]

Comment: Check updated answer..and if you still stuck then update your question with your code...

Comment: In my answer, I have defined `myLinkArray` above `addEventListner` to use inside `addEventListner` but in your code I can not see `arr`,  which you are using inside `addEventListner`